# how to close connection without full the byte array

Tags: java, connection, arrays, telnet

I tried to make a telnet session many times for some devices to send a command. When I run this program it works with the 512 byte character. If I increase the byte size the program doesn't start another session even when the session is closed because there is a 2048 byte character. How can i fix this problem?

```
byte[] buff = new byte[512];
int ret_read = 0;
do {
    ret_read = instr.read(buff);
    if(ret_read > 0) {
        //sending some commands        
    }
} while (ret_read >= 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to use:

```
BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream(), 512);
```